# How to check if the last character of my String is digit or Not.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am creating an ios app and I want to check if the last character of a string that i created from the separation of an other string is digit or letter.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what exactly are you having problem with?

Comment: NSRegularExpression? What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try this

```
NSString *testString = @"testabc123";
unichar character = [testString characterAtIndex:testString.length - 1];
if (isdigit(character)) {
    NSLog(@"It's a digit");
}
else if (isalpha(character)) {
    NSLog(@"It's a character");
}
```

`isdigit` is a standard C function.

**EDIT:** Also added `isalpha` because not every non-digit is a character.

Comment: You cannot call `isdigit()` with a `unichar` argument. From "man isdigit": The argument to `isdigit()` must be representable as a `unsigned char` or the value of `EOF`.

Comment: @MartinR: The parameter of `isdigit()` must be an int, according to the header file `ctype.h`. To my understanding every `unichar` (`unsigned short`) is a valid `int`.

Comment: The parameter is an int, but the function does not allow arbitrary integer arguments. It is documented in the man page, or here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isdigit.html: *"The c argument is an int, the value of which the application shall ensure is a character representable as an unsigned char or equal to the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined."* - In other words, it will work if the string uses only characters in the range 0 .. 255, but otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the String's length and then check the value at the last index. I recommend finding the methods you need to do that here: [NSSTRING CLASS REFERENCE](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function on a substring with the last character of your string

```
-(BOOL)stringIsNumeric:(NSString *)str {

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:str];
    return !!number;

}
```

to use it:

```
    NSString * string = @"1234";
    NSString * lastChar = [string substringFromIndex:string.length-1];   
    [self stringIsNumeric:lastChar];
```